# Listing values in a dictionary where the values are lists

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list that contains only courses from a dictionary where the keys are teachers and the values are a list of courses. The end goal is to have 1 list that is the values (or courses) only.

Sample dict:

```
v = {'Andrew Chalkley': ['jQuery Basics', 'Node.js Basics'],'Kenneth Love': ['Python Basics', 'Python Collections']}
```

my current function:

```
def courses(v):
    full_list = []
    course_list = []
    for key in v.values():
        full_list.append(key)
    for course in full_list:
        course_list = course_list.append(course)
    return course_list
```

I've tested this in IDLE and the first for loop will return a list of lists, the issue seems to be with the second for loop.

Comment: Playing around with it more in Python, I understand that the loop is looking at this as a list of 2 items, those being 2 sub lists. So, I need to pull the data from those secondary lists. Presently, my thought process is to implement .split() in some way to break the lists into separate items to append, but I don't think I'll fix the core issue because the real dictionary would have an unknown number of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for course in full_list:
    course_list.extend(course)
```

Two problems are fixed here:

1. `append` modifies, but returns nothing, so you shouldn't use assignments like that.
2. `extend` adds all the elements in `course` to `course_list`, rather than adding the whole list as a single element.

Comment: Thanks, Aryan. I feel dumb for not trying .extend(), before asking. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
#use sum to concat values from the dict.

sum(v.values(),[])
Out[178]: ['jQuery Basics', 'Node.js Basics', 'Python Basics', 'Python Collections']
```